# Sphinx toctree directive stopped working after update

Tags: python, python-sphinx, fedora, sidebar, toctree

The sphinx HTML documentation I routinely generate has suddenly stopped showing a toctree after updating from fedora 20 to 21. The template is still unchanged, and contains

```
<div class="sidebar">
      {%- block sidebartoc %}
      {{ toctree() }}
      {%- endblock %}
```

which used to create a toctree but now no evidence of a TOC can be seen in the generated div.

No warnings or errors are given, so I don't really know where to start looking. Does anyone have any idea what might have changed recently in sphinx to create this behaviour?

-- Update --

The {{ toctree() }} call doesn't produce any output, regardless of its position in the template, so the "sidebar" bit doesn't seem important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, no idea why, but this fixes it:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  {%- block sidebartoc %}
  {{ toctree(includehidden=True) }}
  {%- endblock %}
```

Will just leave this out there for anyone else experiencing issues after an upgrade...